# How do binary operations with XOR in python work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cryptography, xor

I have the following problem with the xor operator (`^`) in python. I have two binary numbers, let `a = 10100111` and `b = 10000000`. When I use the xor operator,

```
print (10000000 ^ 10100111)
```

I get the result of 166671 instead of 00100111. However, when I use

```
print (100 ^ 101)
```

I get the appropriate result in binary of 1 (001). Even if I use

```
print int(a) ^ int(b)
```

I still get the result of 166671.

**Questions:**

1. Why do I get the result of 166671 instead of the binary result of 00100111?
2. Why do I get the appropriate result when I use 100^101?

I am running Python version 2.7.2.

Comment: Aside: this isn't related to your issue here, but one thing that often surprises people in Python 2 is that `010` isn't either 10 (read in decimal) or 2 (read in binary), it's 8.  The `0` prefix, without a `b`, means "read this number as octal, i.e. base 8".  Just a heads-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`100` is decimal `100` (`1100100` in binary). Use `0bnnn` form for binary representation.

```
>>> 0b100
4
>>> 100
100
>>> 0b100 == 100
False
```

---

```
>>> 0b100 ^ 0b101
1

>>> 0b100 & 0b101
4
>>> bin(0b100 & 0b101)
'0b100'
>>> '{:b}'.format(0b100 & 0b101)
'100'
```

Comment: please tell solution for python 3.x , say x=100 and y=101 x^y

Comment: @AkhilNadhPC, `bin(0b100 ^ 0b101)` works in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

You are using decimal number representations, not binary.

```
10000000^10100111
```

in binary is

```
0b100110001001011010000000 ^ 0b100110100001110110001111
```

which equals

```
0b101000101100001111
```

or in decimal,

```
166671
```

---

```
100 ^ 101
```

in binary is

```
0b1100100 ^ 0b1100101
```

which is

```
0b1
```

or, in decimal (which happens to be the same as in binary in this case),

```
1
```